# How should I use promise in my function to ensure return type correctly

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, promise, async-await

I write a function to retrieve some data from backend server

```
getEventList() {
  return this.request({
    url: '/event/v1/list'
  })
}
```

`getEventList()` return a Promise, but now I need to check local cache first.

```
getEventList() {
  if local cache exists
      return local cache

  return this.request({
    url: '/event/v1/list'
  })
}
```

local cache is an array, and request result is a promise. One function has two different return type, what should I do to keep `getEventList()` return an array in any time ?

Comment: Wrap the cached result in a Promise if it's available, so your function will always return a `Promise<A[]>`

Comment: You should definitely return a `Promise` that resolves with an array. Always **be consistent with what the return type is supposed to be for your function.** Simply do `return Promise.resolve([...])` and that'll do the trick.

Comment: Simply put `this.request(...)` itself into the cache…!

Comment: ^ this is not a good idea because you would be calling multiple `.then`s  on the promise then, and unnecessarily store a whole promise plus associated context... **EDIT:** turns out this can actually have benefits, see below

Comment: You could also just make the function `async`, then it always returns a promise.

Comment: @CherryDT What's the problem with calling multiple `then`s on a promise?

Comment: OK you are right it's not a problem, it's just "weird", maybe it's a matter of taste. And, thinking about it again, caching the whole promise - even though it's not something I'd normally do - could have the benefit of also preventing cache stampede, so could actually be a good idea after all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Return a promise from your cache check as well:

```js
getEventList() {

  if (cached) {
     return Promise.resolve(cacheResult);
  }

  return this.request({
    url: '/event/v1/list'
  })
  
}
```